# SignalR hub OnDisconnected firing time in different browsers after page reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I encountered the situation when my hub's OnDisconnected event happens after the asp.net mvc action on page refresh for the Chrome browser, however for FireFox and IE the behavior is different, the event is fired before the related asp.net mvc action. Is there any fixed rule for this?

The order is important for me, at least i expect it to be the same for all browsers, is there any way to ensure the same order?

Comment: Did you have an answer to your problem?  Below is not the answer I was looking for.  I encountered the exact same problem as you in that Chrome fires off OnDisconnected after the MVC Action.  Did you have a hack for this?

Comment: Well i had to make the changes in the architecture so that i did not need to rely on a certain order. I don't have the solution available at the moment, but i believe i used database to save the information about the event and then processing it after a certain period of time (i had a running timer for that). So this wasn't fully real time, but with a couple of seconds delay, however it helped me to stay independent from the action/event firing order.

Comment: I used the `onBeforeUnload` window event in JavaScript to detect when the user is about to leave the page and fire off a call to the hub/server. This proved accurate as it triggered when the connection will be disconnected, regardless of the order in which SignalR calls `OnDisconnected`. This is a workaround but it worked for me; hope it helps others. I stored the connection ID and other data on the db; with this, I could accurately update that information instead of relying on SignalR's disconnected event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC action or not you cannot ensure order.

Here's why: When a user attempts to navigate away from a page with an active SignalR connection, SignalR will then make a "best effort" attempt to notify the server that the client connection will be stopped.  If our "best effort" attempt fails to reach the server the server will "forget" about the user after a configurable "DisconnectTimeout" later at which time the OnDisconnected event will fire.  If our "best effort" attempt is successful the OnDisconnected event will fire immediately.

Seeing that this behavior is run as a user is leaving a page and is dependent on the client, it can be inconsistent.

Hope this helps!